# Time Series Data Noise Handling Questions

Tags: time-series, noise

There are manufacturing time series data as shown in the picture.

The average of the two variables is about 100.

However, the noise value is 6500 and 65000, which is too different from other values.

I think those are data collection errors or misrecorded noise.

I want to process those values and analyze the time series, is there any way?

I want to use expert domain knowledge to scope and remove it, but it is difficult to meet an expert.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you describe the graphs a little more?  What is x axis what is y axis?

Comment: The x-axis is the number of rows.
The y-axis is a value.
<describe>B.UP TIME :
count:65531, mean:1980.36, std:10847.30, min:0, 25%:118, 50%:127, 75%:138, max:65535
_________________________<describe>HIGH ZONE : count:65531, mean:189.76, std:901.48, min:0, 25%:60.4, 50%:61.9, 75%:63.6, max:6553.5

Comment: Is there a time component involved?  Number of rows on the x-axis doesn't tell me if the occurrences are sequential or not.  If they are just counts, it is not a time series problem.

Comment: Yes, there is no time data, but there is a date. Data with only date recorded.
ex) 2022-05-30